# spring data repository Implenation

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring DATA JPA and selected @Query annotation for creating queries (instead of using NamedQueries and Queries created from MethodName)
I have a data repository as below

```
public interface EventRepository extends CrudRepository<Event, Long> {
    @Query("select e from Event e where e.name = :eventName)
    public List<Event>findEventByName(String eventName );
 }
```

Interface looks good and its enough as per Spring reference doc.

But I need a impl class because I need many other methods in addition to above.

I am facing 2 issues when I create EventRepositoryImpl java implementing EventRepository

1. Its asking to implement all the methods in EventRepository, **findEventByName method is self contained in interface** and why I need implement it again in Impl class?
2. Its asking to implement all the methods in CrudRepository, I know its per OOPS design, But there many methods

So, for these issues can I define my EventRepositoryImpl as abstract, 
this seems to be working fine.

But do I need to worry about anything else, when Spring uses a abstract class as a bean. 
or is there an elegant way to solve this issue.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to implement all of these methods neither create an abstract class. Take a look into official [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations).

```
interface UserRepositoryCustom {
  public void someCustomMethod(User user);
}

class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepositoryCustom {
  public void someCustomMethod(User user) {
    // Your custom implementation
  }
}

interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long>, UserRepositoryCustom {
  // Declare query methods here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.